# Heroku Build doesn’t deploy correctly MERN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

MERN app works in production but when trying to deploy the build on Heroku it fails. Can anyone see why? I'm assuming its going to be something in the server.js file or the package.json but I cant seem to find the issue. Do I need some specific package?

Repo: https://github.com/Joelgiovanni/privateBlogs

Build: https://private-personal-blog.herokuapp.com/

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.K4eJ6/_logs/2019-07-22T18_34_56_240Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! privateblog@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the privateblog@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.K4eJ6/_logs/2019-07-22T18_34_56_254Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Comment: Can you share the content in heroku's log when you deploy?

Comment: Just added logs

Comment: If you run `npm run build` in local, what is the console message? is building correctly? I got doubts coz you are out of /client folder